# How to change class library framework?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, frameworks

Is there a way to change a class library file .NET framework version from .NET4 to .NET2?
I have ocx file written in .NET Framework 4, but my application in which I want to add ocx file in written in .NET framework 2.

**EDIT**
Not ocx file, but Class library.

Comment: an ocx isn't a .net component. do you mean class library

Comment: are you sure its a OCX ? it must be a DLL !

Comment: @DanielA.White Yes I meant class library

Comment: @Brezhnews are you using linq, or tasks?

Comment: @DanielA.White I am not sure, but I think tasks

Comment: are you using `Task<T>`? if so, you can't easily move it back to .net 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments that have been made, it appears that the individual does not have access to the source.  Without the source there is no way to change the .NET version as it requires a re-compile and often times would also require many edits due to language changes.  Especially in the case of .NET 4 -> .NET 2.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the library's source code, you can change the .Net framework version in the Project's properties, however, you may have to edit the code because you may have codes that is supported in the .Net 4 framework but not in the .Net 2 framework.

Answer (score 1):

> And if I don't have the source code

That's going to take Muhammad to go to the mountain.  Create an app.exe.config file with the `<supportedRuntime>` element so that your .NET 2 app is force to load the .NET 4 version of the CLR.

```
<configuration>
   <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
   </startup>
</configuration>
```

Also high time to consider retargeting that app to 4.0.  You'll know you'll have to sooner or later, sooner is knocking loudly on the door.